# Open a combobox in a determinated index C#

Tags: c#

I have this list of a SQL Table

```
1 Guilherme
2 Alejandro
3 Thiago
```

I use this code to populate my combobox1

```
da1.Fill(dt1);
BindingSource src = new BindingSource();
src.DataSource = dt1;
comboBox1.DataSource = src;
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ntj_id";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ntj_descricao";
```

That populates the combobox1 fine, now I want that when the combobox opens, it highlights the value `alejandro`. I have tried this:

```
int abre = comboBox1.FindString("Alejandro"); 
comboBox1.SelectedItem  = abre;
```

But when I write this or this:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = abre;
```

the combobox opens with the actual value highlighted.

Comment: And what does `Empresa Pública` have to do with finding the string that you want to highlight? How do you decide what index it will highlight (logically)?

Comment: I have solved my problem with this code                           'public int natju1;'                                               'natju1 = Convert.ToInt32 (llenar.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString());' 'cmbRma.SelectedValue = natju1;'